# MYSQL - how to get a time difference?

Tags: mysql, time

In MySQL I am trying to select rows from a table that have a `lock_dt` older than 10 hours.  How can I write this sql statement properly?

```
select phone from table where ((now() - lock_dt) < 10 hours)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT phone
FROM table
WHERE lock_dt > NOW() - INTERVAL 10 HOUR
```

Using intervals is pretty handy. Also, I try to isolate the column so an eventual index can be used (sometimes, the RDBMS don't know how to use an index with NOW() - lock_dt, even if there's an index on lock_dt).

Also, the description of your problem contradicts your query. `NOW() - lock_dt < 10 hours` means the interval is *less* than 10 hours. That's what my query do. You have to change > to < if you want *more* than 10 hours.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT phone FROM table WHERE lock_dt < DATE_SUB(now(), interval 10 hour);
```